# How can one include another LiveScript file in LiveScript?

Tags: livescript

How can one use code in a LiveScript file from another LS file? For example:

```
# In script-one.ls
foo = 5

# In script-two.ls
bar = -> foo + 3
```

Simply including both files in the HTML via `script` tags does not seem to work. Changing the first script to `export foo = 5` and using `require! './script-one'` (or variants) in the second script doesn't work either.

And what about circular dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveScript simply compiles to javascript. The module format is your decision just like in JS.

The `export` keyword simply compiles to a commonjs `exports.foo =` right now and will not work in browsers without using something like browserify (http://browserify.org/) to bundle your modules (ES6 compat is planned in the future).